# How should I design an application using Ember.js to suit a given scenario?

Tags: ember.js

I am going to develop an application in ember.js which is kind of a small CRM through which customer representatives can answer to queries of customers.

The layout is pretty simple, I have a 3 column layout.
First column respresent all the queries by customers.
Second column represents the detail of query and section which offers an editor to write and send response to the query
Thrid column consists all templates which customer rep. can use to answer routine questions.

I have prior experience of backbone.js and javascript, but I am still facing difficulty in thinking, in terms of ember.js. In the backbone I would have develop a route which will load the main view with sub views of three column and then there sub views. As ember.js is quite different from backbone, my head is not becoming clear to plan the application.

According to my assumption I would use three models (i.e queries, responses and templates) for a single route, but I am not sure how to do it since emberjs only allows one model to attach with route. Secondly I need a view in response section which can manipulate the queries markup too.

How do you propose to plan this application and think in terms of emberjs?

Answer (score 5):

> According to my assumption I would use three models (i.e queries,
>   responses and templates) for a single route, but I am not sure how to
>   do it since emberjs only allows one model to attach with route.

Ember doesn't actually put this restriction. You can create an RSVP.hash of all the models that you want. Something like:

```
QueryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
          queries: this.store.find('query'),
          details: this.store.find('detail'),
          templates: this.store.find('template'),
          response: this.store.createRecord('response')
       });
  }
})
```

--

As to your question*:

You can create your routes so that there's an index route (which lists all the queries) and there's a query route, which lists the details of a single query, the response, and response templates.

So, your router might look like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("queries", function(){
    this.route("query", { path: "/query/:id" })
  });
});
```

Your queries route might look something like this:

```
QueriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return this.store.find('query'); # this will find all queries
  }
});
```

On your queries template, you can show the list of queries and an outlet so that we can render the query when a user clicks on it.

```
{{#each query in queries}}
    {{#link-to "query" query}}
        {{query.name}}
        {{query.description}}
    {{/link-to}}
{{#each}}


{{ outlet }}
```

Once the user clicks on the query, they will be transitioned to the "query" route. Let's create that route now.

```
QueryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){ 
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
          query: this.store.find('query', params.id),
          details: this.store.find('detail', { query: params.id }),
          templates: this.store.find('template'),
          response: this.store.createRecord('response')
       });
  }
});
```

We're:

a) finding the query for that query ID

b) finding the details for that query ID

c) finding all the templates

d) creating a new response record

On the query template, you can do something like:

```
<div class="query-details">
  <h3>{{query.title}}</h3>
  <small>{{query.description}}</small>

  <p>{{query.details}}</p> # you can loop too if it's an array
</div>

<div class="query-response">
  {{textarea value=response.body}}
  <button {{ action "sendResponse" }}>Send Response</button>
</div>

<div class="templates">
  {{#each template in templates}}
    <h3>{{template.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{template.body}}</p>
    <button {{ action "selectTemplate" template }}>Select Template</button>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Here, you're:

a) rendering the query's title and description as well as its details

b) rendering a response form that has a text area and submit button that has an [action of "sendResponse"](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/), i.e. when you click, it will look up the action "sendResponse" on its controller and the router and keep bubbling up until it finds the action or gets to the applicationRoute at which stage it'll throw an error.

c) rendering the templates and a button to select any template. Notice the action "selectTemplate" that also passes along the "template" parameter.

So... what now? We need to handle these actions and do the right thing. We can do that in two places: the QueryController or the QueryRoute. I'll create a QueryController.

--

There are three types of controllers: Object, Array, and, well, the default controller. An object controller represents a single model and an array controller represents a collection.

In our case, since a query is a single object, we'll use an ObjectController.

So:

```
QueryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {

    sendResponse: function(){
      var response = this.get('response');
      var success  = function(){
        console.log("Successfully posted response!");
      };
      var failure = function(err){
        console.log("Something went wrong:", err);
      };
      response.save().then(success, failure);
    },

    selectTemplate: function(template){
      var response = this.get('response');
      response.get('body').set(template.get('body'));
    }

  }
})
```

There are two actions:

a) sendResponse: takes the response[**] and sends a POST request to your server. Then it executes the success/failure functions when the save() promise resolves.

b) selectTemplate: this just takes the template as parameter and sets the response's body to what the template's body is. Of course, if you have multiple properties, you can [set all of them](http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/working_with_objects/setting_multiple_properties_at_once/).

--

That should put you on the right path. Ember is actually quite easy once you get a hang of the basic conventions it expects you to follow; you may be surprised just how productive you can be with it. :)

--

[*] I'm assuming that you're using Ember Data; if you aren't, I can modify my answer to use normal ajax queries

[**] There's a little bit to explain there: the response object that you created on the route has properties (body, for example) that will automatically change when the user inputs something into the textarea. Thus, when you call save(), it will do the right thing: serialize the model and POST it to your server.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, it literally lighted up some bulbs in my mind. I need to pre populate templates rather then on event of user clicking on query, so I guess rather then including templates model in Query Route I will use it in Queries Route. Also the response section needs to be pre loaded too (not responses) just a form in the middle.

Thanks alot

Comment: No problem. :)

Your use case is possible, too, you're right in that you can preload things on the queries route.